# How to sanitize api response server side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, xss, snyk

I have an Express Request Handler that takes a request, which includes user form input (`email`), makes a request to another one of my (trusted) endpoints (via `newFunctionWithRequest`), and then returns data from that new response (`newResponse`).

```js
export const Handler = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  const { newResponse } = await newFunctionWithRequest(req)
  res.send(newResponse.data) // Snyk identifies this line as the problem
}
```

`Snyk` has identified an `XSS vulnerability`:

```
Unsanitized input from the HTTP request body flows into send, where it is used to render an HTML page returned to the user. This may result in a `Cross-Site Scripting attack (XSS)`
```

How can I fix this vulnerability?

Comment: If you trust the server, and this functionality is intentional then it doesn't sound like this is a vulnerability.

Comment: Are you sending JSON back to the client?

Comment: Also `Snyk` should be giving you some remediation examples in the UI, when you click on the issue. Can you share what they are and if they were relevant?

Comment: @slebetman yes the data from the server response

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend getting the specific elements from the request object `req`, and then passing them into the `newFunctionWithRequest` function. This means that the function is not receiving anything it isn't expecting.

For example:

```
export const Handler = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    const { newResponse } = await newFunctionWithRequest({ email, password });
    res.send(newResponse.data);
}
```

You could also validate that it is the correct type, and sanitise it too if you wanted.

Another option is you could use a library like [Joi](https://joi.dev/) to validate your incoming requests.

Answer (score 0):

When I had similar requirements, I created custom middleware that you can integrate into any endpoint (or globally for every request), and it will check if any of the inputs in the request `body` is problematic.

It will check if:

- The input contains some embedded HTML code (scripts of images for example).
- First non-white character is `=`, which make Excel imports vulnerable.

---

**Middleware**

```
const containsHtml = /<[^>]*>/;
const startsWithEqual = /^\s*=/;

const isInvalidInput = (input) => {
  return containsHtml.test(input) || startsWithEqual.test(input);
}

exports.inputValidator = (req,res,next) => {
  let invalid_input_count = 0;
  const obj = req.body;
  const stack = [obj];
  while (stack?.length > 0) {
    const currentObj = stack.pop();
    Object.keys(currentObj).forEach(key => {
      if (typeof currentObj[key] === 'object' && currentObj[key] !== null) {
        stack.push(currentObj[key]);
      } else {
        if (typeof currentObj[key] === 'string' && isInvalidInput(currentObj[key])) {
          invalid_input_count++;
        }
      }
    });
  }

  if(invalid_input_count === 0) {
    return next();
  } else{
    return res.status(400).json({ success: false, error_code: 'invalid_input'});
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```
const express = require('express');
const { inputValidator } = require('./util/input-validator');

...

const app = express();
app.use(inputValidator); // Check every request for vulnerable inputs
```

Answer (score -2):

**DOMPurify** works server-side or client-side.

I believe that is the sort of library you are looking for.

https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify

Comment: I believe DOMPurify expects a DOM node or a string. In my example I am passing data from a response object.